How to create log message for commands on discord bot
I try to create a channel where the bot post the commands used but nothing I tried worked.
from discord import *
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
guild = discord.Object(id = 0)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready() :
    print(f'{bot.user.name} est actif')
    
    global LOG_CMD
    LOG_CMD = bot.get_channel(1230504051616124974)

(here @events I tried)


@bot.tree.command(name = "test", description = "X")
async def cmd_test(interaction : discord.Interaction) :
    await interaction.channel.send("testtt")

@client.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    print(f'Commande exécutée: {ctx.command} par {ctx.author}')

(tried with bot.event)
@bot.before_invoke
async def before_any_command(ctx):
    print(f'Commande exécutée: {ctx.command} par {ctx.author}')

nothing happen for both
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("trigger")
    print(message.content)

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('/'):
        print("trigger2")
        user_mention = message.author.mention
        command_and_arguments = message.content
        log_content = f"{user_mention} used: {command_and_arguments}"
        print(log_content)
        await bot.process_commands(message)

for this one it print
trigger
testtt

so the message is recognize but witout the "/" of the command as show message.content
and the bot send "testtt" so the command is activated for each try, there is no errors
here I use print just to see if it works but I will use a channel.send()
EDIT add main part of the bot

Please edit your question to include how you defined bot and/or client, and the intents used. Also, specify exactly what happened with what you tried, and include errors if you got any.
